# Autoescalado app con windows form

Tags: c#, visual-studio

He realizado una aplicación de windows form con visual studio, en la que cada formulario tiene un tamaño de 1920 x 1080, ya que esta pensada para pantallas de dicha resolución.

El problema esta en que app la he realizado con un portátil de 15' que tiene un escalado del 150%, y al ejecutar la aplicación sale todo perfecto. El problema aparece al abrir el ejecutable en mi ordenador(monitor de 24' con escalado del 100%), ya que me aparecen unos bordes a la derecha y abajado del formulario.

He probado con el AutoScaleMode en todos los tipos y no he conseguido resolver nada.

Se agradece la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Para que los controles escalen cuando amplias o disminuyes el form te debes basar en el uso del `Anchor` y `Dock`, son las unicas formas que soporta winform, sino deberias evaluar pasarte a `WPF`

[Dynamically Resizing Controls On Windows Forms - Using Anchor Property](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c5c6e2/dynamically-resizing-controls-on-windows-forms-using-ancho/)

[Configuring Your Form for Resizing](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=102148&seqNum=5)

en estos articulo oficiales sobre `Windows Forms` explica como aplicar estas propiedades

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Ajustar el tamaño y la escala de formularios Windows Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/adjusting-the-size-and-scale-of-windows-forms)

[Ajuste automático de escala en Windows Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/automatic-scaling-in-windows-forms)

Tambien dispones de los controles

[TableLayoutPanel (Control, formularios Windows Forms)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/tablelayoutpanel-control-windows-forms)

[FlowLayoutPanel (Control, formularios Windows Forms)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/flowlayoutpanel-control-windows-forms)

Para organizar el diseño y que este se acomode a las dimensiones del form

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, probaré a ver si consigo el resultado esperado